# JavaMail and IP4 vs IP6

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-mail

I'm sending mail through JavaMail to a mailserver on localhost, port 25.
My mailserver binds to IP4 only, i.e. it binds to `127.0.0.1:25`, but not to `[::]:25`.

With JavaMail 2.5.1 and JDK 1.7.0_45 I can only get this to work if I set System Property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

Questions:

1. Why do I need to set the System Property?  What I mean is why isn't
   it enough in JavaMail to set my target host as `127.0.0.1` rather
   than `localhost`. I would assume that using an explicit IP4 address
   would be sufficient to tell Java that I want to use an IP4
   connection?
2. Ok, let's say I really need that System Property. I'm inside a J2EE
   server and I really do not want to mess with the other tenants on
   the same J2EE server. If I set it programmatically in my code, as in
   `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack","true")` will it then affect other tenants in the J2EE server ?
3. What I really want to do is to make sure that only that SMTP connection uses IP4. Within the application there's a lot of other TCP connection going on not related to SMTP. I don't want to limit those to use IP4-only. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Grazie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

The problem is that using property `mail.smtp.host=127.0.0.1` doesn't force use of IP4 as I had expected.

The trick is to use property `mail.smtp.localaddress=127.0.0.1` as well. This will bind the outgoing socket to this local address and thus make it IP4.

The properties for the SMTP connection in JavaMail are documented [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html).

I'm assuming that the problem can also be solved by creating a custom *SocketFactory* class and then let JavaMail know that this class should be used by way of the `mail.smtp.socketFactory.class` property.